# Insertion and deletion of rows in UITableView sometimes causes the crash?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewanimation

I am doing very usual stuff. 
First modifying the data model and then updating the TableView. But sometimes app crashes. 
And throws error something like that (depends on insertion or deletion).

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (10) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (10), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).
```

Here is my insertion code.

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.stories insertObject:story atIndex:0];
NSArray *indexPaths = @[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

and Deletion code.

```
[tableview beginUpdates];
[stories removeObject:story];
NSIndexPath *indexpath = [tableview indexPathForCell:cell];
if(indexpath) {
    [tableview deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexpath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
}
[tableview endUpdates];
```

Comment: It looks like `[stores removeObject:story]` may be the culprit. Check to make sure story is in stories in all cases, since it looks like there's 10, and you are trying to delete one, but the data source still has 10 objects.

Comment: The `[tableview reloadData]` looks suspect to me...

Comment: @Both: I'd very much prefer [stores removeObjectAtIndex:], and the reloadData is definitely wrong at that place - it will badly interfere with the deleteRowsAtIndexPaths and lead to a crash if the last line is deleted.

Comment: Hey guys updated the question, here @stefandouganhyde relaodData never used there. I accidently posted that here.

Comment: calling the `–deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` method is in a condition's _true_ branch only; and here comes the inconsistency: you remove the object from your model _without condition_, but you delete the row _conditionally only_ – which may be evaluated or may not be, and if not, you just get the crash. it would be really essential to know why do you need to call the `[tableview indexPathForCell:cell]` method? as you must have had the correct `indexPath` in your delegate method...

Comment: @holex the deletion call in is some other method not in delegate. so have to use indexPathForCell as that method has cell but not indexpath. And true condition I put to stop the crash the crash was happening before also.

Comment: @kidsid49, you have just found the glitch in your design pattern, which leads to crash; put into the delegate method and use the `indexPath` which the system sent you for deletion, and there won't be any crash.

Answer (score 6):

Insertion Code:

```
[self.stories insertObject:story atIndex:0];

[self.tableView beginUpdates];
NSArray *indexPaths = @[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Deletion Code:

```
[stories removeObject:story];

[tableview beginUpdates];
NSIndexPath *indexpath = [tableview indexPathForCell:cell];
[tableview deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexpath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
[tableview endUpdates];
```

Note: You should not add/remove object to an array inside updating your tableview's rows.

Comment: For a single insertion / deletion operation `begin/endUpdates` is not needed at all.

Comment: @vadian, please correct me if I'm wrong, but from [Apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/beginUpdates) `"...If you do not make the insertion, deletion, and selection calls inside this block, table attributes such as row count might become invalid..."` And for this question OP is doing both the things. Thus, this might be correct and required.

Comment: The crucial word is `calls` (plural) referring to `if you want subsequent ... calls`

Answer (score 0):

Either do `[tableview reloadData];` or `[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];`

Also you are doing database operation in-between `[self.tableView beginUpdates];`
and `[self.tableView endUpdates];`. It's not proper.

As per the error suggests, there is a mismatch in table view rows and data source of that table view.